# Como utilizar propriedades personalizadas do demoiselle.properties

Tags: java, demoiselle

Gostaria de saber como eu poderia utilizar a classe do `demoiselle.properties` para utilizar minhas propriedades personalizadas.

Ex.:

```
# Propriedades personalizadas do sistema
sistema.id.documento = 10
sistema.processo.seguranca = true
// ...
```

e utilizar isso em alguma `classe java`, como por exemplo, a classe "`properties`":

É possível utilizar esse tipo de configuração?

Answer (score 0):

Recebi este link de um dos colaboradores do Demoiselle.

http://demoiselle.sourceforge.net/docs/framework/reference/2.5.0-RC1/html/configuracao.html

É exatamente o que estava precisando!

Segue o mesmo Este exemplo segue o mesmo conceito do spring.